# Marshal global variable in C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling

I have 3 global variables in the C code: one int and two pointers to structures. I have to marshal them as public static members in the C# code, but i couldn't find any solution. I must mention that modifying the C code is the absolute last option.

I have to marshal this global:

```
extern const    msdk_FileSystemInterface*       m_fileInterface;
```

This is what i've tried so far, but doesn't compile:

```
    [DllImport("foo.so", EntryPoint = "m_fileInterface")]
    private static extern IntPtr _m_fileInterface { get; set; }
    public static msdk_FileSystemInterface m_fileInterface 
    { 
        get
        {
            return (msdk_FileSystemInterface)Marshal.PtrToStructure(_m_fileInterface, typeof(msdk_FileSystemInterface));
        }
    }
```

.

```
    [DllImport("foo.so", EntryPoint = "m_fileInterface")]
    private static extern IntPtr _m_fileInterface;
    public static msdk_FileSystemInterface m_fileInterface 
    { 
        get
        {
            return (msdk_FileSystemInterface)Marshal.PtrToStructure(_m_fileInterface, typeof(msdk_FileSystemInterface));
        }
    }
```

msdk_FileSystemInterface structure is available in the C# code (is already marshaled).

**Does anyone have a solution for marsahalling globals or is impossible and I really have to them wrap them in a struct or add setters and getters into the C code?**

Comment: It's impossible. You'll have to do the thing you didn't want to do, unfortunately.

Comment: @Matthew It's is not impossible. GetProcAddress solves it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh cool! I didn't know about that! It's impossible to marshal it though ofc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GetProcAddress to obtain the address of the exported globals. You cannot get the marshaller to do it with DllImport.

So your two options are:

1. Use GetProcAddress and do all the marshalling yourself.
2. Add getters and setters to the C code and let the marshaller do the heavy lifting from there.

Personally I would opt for option 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will opt for the setter and getter two. Using GetProcAddress is not an option for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this was (correctly) answered in 2013, but since .net core 3.0 (released in 2019) it's possible to get the address of an exported symbol using [NativeLibrary.GetExport(IntPtr, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.nativelibrary.getexport?view=netcore-3.0#system-runtime-interopservices-nativelibrary-getexport(system-intptr-system-string)) method:

```
IntPtr libHandle = NativeLibrary.Load("path/to/nativelib.dll"); // or .so or .dylib
IntPtr exportHandle = NativeLibrary.GetExport(libHandle, "m_fileInterface");
msdk_FileSystemInterface m_fileInterface = Marshal.PtrToStructure<msdk_FileSystemInterface>(exportHandle);
```